# KD-Tree implementation

Tags: data-structures, tree, machine-learning, kdtree

I'm trying to write my own KD-Tree implementation and eventually a kNN implementation. and I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding how the KD-Tree construct the search tree.

on wikipedia it says that it finds the median of the values and use that as the root of the tree.

When there are many dimensions however, how would u compute the median?

Answer (score 2):

You don't find the median in several dimensions (in fact, there is no meaningful order for multidimensional numbers). At every level of the kd Tree, you focus on one dimension. You choose the median based on this dimension, ignoring other components.

Note that you can use many criteria other than the median, depending on what you want to do. Likewise, selecting a good scheme for deciding the dimension for each node is an art, though virtually every scheme is *correct*.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *required* to find the medians:  from wikipedia:

> Note also that it is not required to select the median point. In that
>   case, the result is simply that there is no guarantee that the tree
>   will be balanced. A simple heuristic to avoid coding a complex
>   linear-time median-finding algorithm, or using an O(n log n) sort of
>   all n points, is to use sort to find the median of a fixed number of
>   randomly selected points to serve as the splitting plane. In practice,
>   this technique often results in nicely balanced trees.

[KD-Tree from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort the points according to one dimension, then choose
the median as root, then recursively construct subtrees(sort with other dimension)
here is an implementation:
https://github.com/tavaresdong/cs106l/blob/master/KDTree/src/KDTree.h